# How to avoid Binding Error when parent is removed

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, styles

I am working on a WPF project, and I am creating some styles, one of them is the `DataGridCell` style, it works fine.

My problem is that: **When the user delete any row, many errors are shown in the Visual Studio's Output window.**

This is the error:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 
 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid', 
 AncestorLevel='1''.
 BindingExpression:Path=CanUserAddRows; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridCell' 
 (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

So, I guess the error is because when the `DataGridCell` is removed from the `DataGrid`, the binding does not find the the Parent, but, **What can I do to avoid getting these errors?? I mean, how can I establish a condition for the binding??**

My XAML Style code is as following:

```
<DataGrid Margin="6,25,6,35" x:Name="dataGrid">            
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=CanUserAddRows}" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#A4A4A4"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
. . . . .
```

Hope someone can help me,  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced this kind of problems and setting [TargetNullValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx) and [FallbackValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx) gets rid of these binding errors most of the time.

```
<MultiDataTrigger.Conditions> 
   <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                         AncestorType= {x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=CanUserAddRows, 
                         TargetNullValue=False, FallbackValue=False}" Value="False" /> 
   <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                         Path=IsSelected, TargetNullValue=False, 
                         FallbackValue=False}" Value="True" /> 
</MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
```

In general, I also try to minimize the use of `RelativeSource` as much as possible, use `DataContext` wherever possible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am new in WPF, and I have a question, this answer can be applied in a `Condition`'s `Binding` property??

Comment: @Dante Yes you can, these are properties of Binding class so they will work for every Binding; added code for ref.

Comment: Hi akjoshi, I just tried what you suggest but I am still receiving the same errors

Comment: I think that was mine. I upvoted Dante's coment rather than re-post it. Sorry for the confusion. Is this answer still relevant? I seem to remember somewhere that it's okay to downvote outdated answers so that SO's content is always up to date.

Comment: Hi @hypehuman, Thanks for the reply; I am not aware of any changes or new feature to replace this, I still use TargetNull and FallBack attributes and they work in most of the cases but it might also depend on visual tree and notifications etc.